# Ссылочный аргумент функции по умолчанию

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки

```
bool IsNullVector(const VectorClass &Vector)
```

Прототип моей функции, нужно назначить по умолчанию значение ему, пытался NULL, и инициализировать объект еще раз и присвоить но выдает ошибку, как можно решить?

Comment: Ссылки обязательно должны быть инициализированы, смените тип аргумента на указатель или сделайте так, чтобы VectorClass имел возможное состояние "не инициализировано".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать, создав константную ссылку на временный объект. Например,

```
bool IsNullVector(const VectorClass &Vector = VectorClass() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Только передачей указателя.

```
bool IsNullVector(const VectorClass *VectorPtr = nullptr) 
{
    if (VectorPtr)
    {
        const VectorClass& VectorRef = *VectorPtr;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Примерно так.

Ссылка может существовать только на корректный, существующий объект.

(Нет, конечно, есть варианты... но лучше вам их пока не знать :))

Comment: В функцию что мне передавать? Указатель на объект?